# how can I make a dynamic form for days of the week and time?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, time, datetimepicker

I have been looking for a while with no luck.
I am trying to write a form in html that is dynamic. The user will first select the weekday (Eg Monday) and then can select the time in 30 minute increments (eg 2:30pm).

I know it is possible to get the time form from DateTimePicker, and I can make a simple options form for the weekdays, but is there any way to connect the two into the same form dynamically?

Thanks a lot,

Comment: Can you show us what you've got so far?

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
var select = document.createElement('SELECT');
select.name = "days";

var days = ['Sunday','Monday','Tuesday','Wednesday','Thursday','Friday','Saturday'];

for (var i = 0; i < days.lentgh; i++)
{
    var option = document.createElement('OPTION');
    option.value = days[i];
    option.textContent = days[i];
    select.body.appendChild(option);
}

document.body.appendChild(select);


var select = document.createElement('SELECT');
select.name = "time";

for (var i = 0; i < (24*2); i++)
{
    var option = document.createElement('OPTION');
    var x = (i % 2 === 0) ? '30' : '00';
    var y = (i / 2) + ':' + x;  
    option.value = y;
    option.textContent = y;
}

document.body.appendChild(select);
```

You can in "document.body.appendChild(select);" body repace with e.g. getElementById('yourId')